# dispatcher timer interval

Tags: c#, time, intervals, dispatcher

I have my dispathcer working and it is looking like this;

```
            timer.Tick +=
                delegate(object s, EventArgs args)
                {

                    timeDuration.Text = counter++.ToString();

                };

            timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,1); 
            timer.Start();
```

Now its counting the second starting at 0 at ticks 0,1,2,3,4,5 and so on.
How do i make so when its counting its looks like this

```
00:00:00
```

Comment: Why do you use delegate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`timeDuration.Text = Timespan.FromSeconds(counter++).ToString();` should do it.

Comment: This made it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

use

```
timeDuration.Text = ((counter++ / 3600) + "").PadLeft(2, '0') + ":" + (((counter % 3600) / 60) + "").PadLeft(2, '0') + ":" + ((counter % 60) + "").PadLeft(2, '0');
```